# Please explain「何が? 」

Tags: grammar, anime

From: No Game No Life ep.2 timestamp: 00:05

Context: One of the characters is asking what's going on, and the other is confused about what exactly is being asked.

> どういうことですの？
>
> え？何が？

What's supposed to be understood after 何が in this incomplete sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the equivalent of a question to clarify information for further processing:
"About what?" or "What is?"